# What is the difference between "hg grep" and "hg locate"?

Tags: mercurial

I expected `hg grep` to be a synonym for `hg locate`, but it turns out that it is a different command. `hg locate` should search for files matching a pattern in a single division by default, while `grep` normally searches backwards through all revisions (but can be restricted to a single revision or range).

What is the reason for these two seemingly overlapping commands? Are they intended for different use cases? I cannot infer any reasonable division of labour between them.

Incidentally, I couldn't get `locate` to return anything when I call it with a pattern (one I know to be present in tracked files). If I'm misunderstanding something, please enlighten me (but this is for background only; the question is about `grep` vs. `locate`).

```
% hg locate BoolNative
%
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are totally different commands (incidentally, `hg locate` is deprecated, because its functionality is now subsumed under `hg files`).

Briefly, `hg grep` searches the *contents* of files; `hg locate` searches the *file list* and the pattern is meant to match *file names*, not file contents (the functionality of `hg locate` is roughly equivalent to the Unix `find` command restricted to version-controlled files).

In your example, you're trying to use `hg locate` to search the contents of files, which will not work.